# Unreal - Move players's camera and hands at the same time

Tags: animation, unreal-engine4

I'm new to Unreal Engine and I want to make a First-Person game. I want my player to climb on top of a cube.

So I created a Camera animation, in order to see that the player is climbing (the camera goes up, then rotates a little, then goes forward). When the player is climbing the cube, I also want their hands to grasp the edge of the platform and push in the upward direction. I don't have a full skeleton, only hands like in the basic first-player example.

So basically, when the player presses space in front of a cube, I'd like to have my camera animation and my hand animation to play at the same time and to be synchronized.

**Is there any animation class to do both in the same class ? Like a montage, or a sequence. When I go to animation montage, I can't find anything to import my camera animation.**

When I create a new skeleton animation, there is no camera attached to the skeleton so I cannot move the camera and the hands in the same animation.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Root Motion](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Engine/Animation/RootMotion) can do this. With Root Motion, you wouldn't animate the camera directly. Instead, you'd animate the character's root bone to move the character capsule (and thus camera). This would keep the camera and hands in sync and also allow you to implement your climb.

Stack Overflow isn't the best place to ask animation questions. I'd recommend one of the following instead:

- [Anim State](http://www.animstate.com/community/) (which also has a discord server)
- [UE4 Animation Forum](https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/animation)

Comment: Thank for your answer!